# java using ExecutorService is not accelerating the program

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I call a rest client service using Executor Service. I check times in serial or parallel, it takes the same time.

```
List<String> exeParallel(int start, int end){
List<String> people =  new ArrayList<String>();
byte maxthreads;
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    maxthreads =  (byte) ((cores > 2)?cores-1:1); 
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxthreads);

for(Long i= start; i <= end; i++ ){
        Callable<ServiceResponse> callTask = getTask(i);
        Future<ServiceResponse> future = executor.submit(callTask);
   if(future != null){
       String result = .....;
       people.add(result);
    }
}

private Callable<ServiceResponse> getTask(int num){
return new Callable<ServiceResponse>(){
    @Override
    public ServiceResponsecall() throws Exception {
    ServiceRestClient serviceRestClient =ServiceRestClient.getInstance();
            return serviceRestClient.callservice(num);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Well, if you block with `get()` on the future (which is the relevant code that you replaced with `....`), it is certainly going to take the same time. What it is you want to do?

Comment: @Tunaki I want to take the response and copy the relevant data that I need to a string

Answer (score 0):

Submit all the tasks first, *then* get the results from them one at a time. This means that while you are waiting for the first result, the others may also be running at the same time.

```
List<Future<ServiceResponse>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for(Long i= start; i <= end; i++ )
    futures.add(executor.submit(getTask(i)));

for (Future<ServiceResponse> future : futures)
{
    if(future != null)
    {
        String result = .....;
        people.add(result);
    }
}
```